# Registering object members in Python at import time

Tags: python, subclass

I have a set of classes, which represent different "tools", each of which have an ID key, a description, a title and a few other constants. These are all subclassed from a "GenericTool" class.

I would like to have a way to fill a dictionary, keyed on the IDs of all the subclasses, so that I can easily look up the constants, given the ID, but without having to maintain a central dictionary.

For example, file `tools/toola.py`

```
import generic_tool as GT
class ToolA(GT.GenericTool):

    title = "Tool A"
    id = "tool_a"
```

File `tools/toolb.py`

```
import generic_tool as GT
class ToolB(GT.GenericTool):

    title = "Tool B"
    id = "tool_b"
```

I would like to end up with a dictionary like this:

```
{ 'tool_a': {'title': 'Tool A'},
  'tool_b': {'title': 'Tool B'} }
```

I have looked at using a metaclass, and code in the superclass `__init__()`, but these seem to affect the run-time creation of classes, whereas I am concerned with doing it only once, when the modules are first imported.

Comment: "*but without having to maintain a central dictionary.*": why?

Comment: Because it seems neater to have the class-specific info in the class, without having to look after a totally decoupled list, which can easy go out of sync. For a couple of classes, sure, you can do it by hand, but for hundreds or more, it's not going to scale well, and I can envisage something a bit like a decorator where this information is gathered automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that "without having to maintain a central dictionary" really means "without having to maintain a manually updated dictionary" a solution to this would be by using meta classes. This would require a definition of `generic_tool.GenericTool` to be like this:

```
class GenericToolMeta(type):
    """Meta classs that is used by Tools to register in a central dictionary."""
    tools = {}

    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        new_class = type.__new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict)

        try:
            meta.tools[new_class.id] = new_class.title
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return new_class

class GenericTool(object):
    __metaclass__ = GenericToolMeta
```

When using the `__metaclass__` declaration in your base (`GenericTool`) or directly in your derived `Tools` the classes themselves get registered automatically upon definition (i.e. import-time as you call it):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import generic_tool
>>> generic_tool.GenericToolMeta.tools
{}
>>> import toola
>>> generic_tool.GenericToolMeta.tools
{'tool_a': 'Tool A'}
>>> import toolb
>>> generic_tool.GenericToolMeta.tools
{'tool_a': 'Tool A', 'tool_b': 'Tool B'}
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, I did mean "manually maintain", which does seem to have caused some confusion. Apparently I also totally misunderstood when `__new__` was called. Thanks for a very clear example!

Answer (score 1):

Metaclasses:

```
class GenericToolMeta(type):
    tool_dict = {}

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        tool_dict[cls.id] = {'title': cls.title}
        super(GenericToolMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
```

```
import generic_tool as GT
class ToolB(GT.GenericTool, metaclass=GT.GenericToolMeta):
    title = "Tool B"
    id = "tool_b"
```

Or with decorators:

```
tool_list = []

def tool(title, id):
    def decorator(cls):
        cls.title = title
        cls.id = id
        tool_list[id] = title
        return cls

    return decorator
```

```
import generic_tool as GT

@GT.tool(id="tool_b", title="Tool B")
class ToolB(GT.GenericTool):
    # ...
```